# Preserve all classes in the shared project in release build

Tags: xamarin.forms, linker, release

I'm developing cross platform app using Xamarin.Forms, and I had some pain with the linker to build the release version. I use MVVM pattern, dependency injection for some services, value converters, behaviors, markup extensions... I've had to use the `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` attribute on many classes so that the linker wouldn't remove them.

Is it any way to preserve all shared project classes and members without using `Preserve` attribute in all *"not used"* files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can [exclude entire assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#skipping-assemblies) from the iOS Linker

in the "additional mtouch arguments" under iOS project options

```
--linkskip=NameOfAssemblyToSkipWithoutFileExtension
```

in Android, you can use [linkskip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#linkskip)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidLinkSkip>Assembly1;Assembly2</AndroidLinkSkip>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you, checked in Android. I can't check in iOS now, but it seems that this will work.